# Why does my canvas window not show the moving polygon that I created?

Tags: python, tkinter, polygon, tkinter-canvas

This code attempts to move a triangle across the canvas.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400)
canvas.pack
canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 60, 50, 35)
for x in range(0, 60):
    canvas.move(1, 5, 0)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Unfortunately, whenever I run the program, it pulls up the canvas window but doesn't show the triangle at all. I'm using Version 3.7.
What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

`canvas.pack` should be `canvas.pack()`.  The canvas is never shown.

Comment: haha, have some good rep for picking the low hanging fruits @acw1668

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @acw1668, your mistake is to forget to call (using `()`) the `pack` method of the `canvas` widget.

However, there are more quirks to address in your code:

- `time.sleep` in a GUI makes it non responsive; don't do that, use `tk.after` instead.
- using `tk` to name your `root` is a rather bad idea, especially for others that will read your code.
- star imports are not recommended.
- the use of `tk.update` is also not recommended when the mainloop can automatically run the GUI.

here is an example that avoids the above points:

```
import tkinter as tk


def move_polygon(i=0):
    canvas.move(polygon, 5, 0)
    if i < 60:
        canvas.after(50, move_polygon, i+1)


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=400)
canvas.pack()

polygon = canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 60, 50, 35)
move_polygon()

root.mainloop()
```